# What is the sql query in SQLite, to retrieve the records from the database table for the last week, for the last month, and for the last year

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I created a data base table using SQLite in my project, I want to retrieve records from the database for  the last week,  for the last month,  for the last year, when user click on the specified Buttons.                                                                                      But I don't know how to retrieve the records. Is there any function exist to get these records accordingly ?

Comment: Is the time stored as a column in the table?

Comment: You need the name of a table to select from, and some timestamp-like column in that table.

Comment: @Tiru, please take care to tag your question appropriately. That way more people will see it. Also, it won't hurt if you click the empty tick mark next to the answer that helped you.

Comment: Thanks to All for your Response

Comment: Hi IIya Kogan, thanks for ur suggn, but now I am a new user here.So it seems good ,if you say how to increase the rate....

Comment: You need to up-vote answers that are helpful.  And if one is a workable solution you click the check mark next to it. (It will turn green)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the query

```
SELECT * FROM DATABASE_TABLE
    WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d',DATE) >= date('now','-6 days') AND 
    strftime('%Y-%m-%d',DATE)<=date('now') order by DATE
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to construct a "where" clause like so:

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor groupCur = cr.query(
                Groups.CONTENT_URI, // what table/content
                new String [] {Groups._ID, Groups.NAME},    // what columns
                "Groups.NAME NOT LIKE + 'System Group:%'", // where clause(s)
                null, // ???
                Groups.NAME + " ASC" // sort order
        );
```

I spaced this out so it's easier to explain, but this is what you typically see as:

```
Cursor groupCur = cr.query(Groups.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
```